# The linear layout format keeps showing errors, I've tried all I can but still not working.?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout, android-linearlayout

Have being trying to build this layout but I don't while its not running yet
'''

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#90A4AE"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

'''

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: do you close LinearLayout?

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to close the Linear Layout !
Use the code below.
Always remember that you have to close the tag either by using ".../>" at end or "</..>" after adding widgets inside it...

Please note that I also replaced the old support library tablayout with a tablayout from material library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#90A4AE"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp">
    
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```